# Setting max-old-space-size in Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: node.js, azure-devops

My "IIS Web App Deploy" starts failing to deploy zip package when its size exceeded 200MB. The error is `FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory`

The solution must be to increase node memory with max-old-space-size option e.g. `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("NODE_OPTIONS", "--max-old-space-size=16384", "Machine")`

However, whatever I do does not help. Always the same error. I tried setting env variable and can confirm that it changes (I check env variables via My computer on Windows). I also tried `set NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8192` but IIS Web App Deploy task always fails with the same error message.

I added a Power Shell script to check node memory size with simple js script

```
const v8 = require('v8');
const totalHeapSize = v8.getHeapStatistics().total_available_size;
const totalHeapSizeGb = (totalHeapSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024).toFixed(2);
console.log('totalHeapSizeGb: ', totalHeapSizeGb);
```

and if I run this script locally it shows amended size but if I run it as a task in the pipeline it ways shows default totalHeapSizeGb:  1.39

My question is How to change max-old-space-size for node so IIS Web App Deploy task use it instead of default value and stops failing?

Comment: Not get your latest information, is the workaround helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 1):

`increase-memory-limit` is a workaround to fix `heap out of memory` when running node binaries. It's a common issue when using TypeScript 2.1+ and webpack.

**How to use**

```
npm install -g increase-memory-limit
```

Run from the root location of your project:

```
increase-memory-limit
```

**Running from NPM task**

Alternatively, you can configure a npm task to run the fix

```
// ...
  "scripts": {
    "fix-memory-limit": "cross-env LIMIT=2048 increase-memory-limit"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "increase-memory-limit": "^1.0.3",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.5"
  }
// ...


npm run fix-memory-limit
```

Here is the [document](https://www.npmjs.com/package/increase-memory-limit) you can refer to.

Comment: I've used this `"fix-memory-limit": "cross-env LIMIT=2048 increase-memory-limit"` but getting this error : `npm ERR! JSON.parse Unexpected token " " (0xA0) in JSON at position 695 while parsing near "... \"fix-memory-limit\": \"cross-env LIMIT=40..."` when running `npm run fix-memory-limit`.

Comment: Update, figured out you can run this command in your build `npm run build -- --no-optimization`.